# Extend a type with associated Types that have generic associated types

Tags: swift, generics

I'd like to make the following code more generic.

```
typealias DataFrameStrategyResult = Result<DataFrame.Strategy, DataFrame.StrategyError>

extension Array where Element == DataFrameStrategyResult {

    typealias StrategiesAction = ([DataFrame.Strategy]) -> Void
    typealias ErrorsAction = ([DataFrame.StrategyError]) -> Void
    
    func success(
        _ successAction: StrategiesAction,
        errors errorsAction: ErrorsAction
    ) {
        errorsAction(compactMap { $0.failure })
        successAction(compactMap { $0.success })
    }
}
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
extension Array where Element == Result {

    typealias StrategiesAction = ([Element.Success]) -> Void
    typealias ErrorsAction = ([Element.Failure]) -> Void
    
    func success(
        _ successAction: StrategiesAction,
        errors errorsAction: ErrorsAction
    ) {
        errorsAction(compactMap { $0.failure })
        successAction(compactMap { $0.success })
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm having trouble extending a type with an associated type that has other associated types because the compiler is requiring that I specify the specific types, while I'd rather keep them generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are after is "generic" extensions, which is a feature that is [proposed and being worked on at the moment](https://forums.swift.org/t/parameterized-extensions/25563).

In the proposed syntax, you would do:

```
extension<S, F: Error> Array where Element == Result<S, F> {

    typealias StrategiesAction = ([S]) -> Void
    typealias ErrorsAction = ([F]) -> Void
    
    func success(
        _ successAction: StrategiesAction,
        errors errorsAction: ErrorsAction
    ) {
        errorsAction(compactMap { $0.failure })
        successAction(compactMap { $0.success })
    }
}
```

But you can't do exactly that right now, since the feature is still WIP.  There is a work around though. Since methods can be generic, (at least in this case) you can add the generic parameters to the method instead, rather than on the extension.

```
extension Array {
    
    func success<S, F: Error>(
        _ successAction: ([S]) -> Void,
        errors errorsAction: ([F]) -> Void
    ) where Element == Result<S, F>
    {
        errorsAction(compactMap { $0.failure })
        successAction(compactMap { $0.success })
    }
}

extension Result {
    var failure: Failure? {
        if case .failure(let f)  = self {
            return f
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    var success: Success? {
        try? get()
    }
}
```

However, the type aliases can't be generic, so you have to live without them.

This is only a work around, and not truly a "generic" extension, because `success` is now a function on all arrays. It is just that for arrays of non-`Result`, its generic constraints are not satisfied, so you can't use it.

Comment: Why not simply `var success: Success? { try? get() }`?

Comment: @LeoDabus Haha, I guess I've been thinking of `Result` as an enum too much...